# Type 'Omit<T & { _id: string; }, "_id">' is not assignable to type 'T'

Tags: typescript

I'm experiencing a type error:

```
Type 'Omit<T & { _id: string; }, "_id">' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'Omit<T & { _id: string; }, "_id">'
```

I'm expecting `Omit<T & {_id: string;}, "_id">` to be equal to `T` logically, but it's throwing an error. Can anyone explain why?

Context:

```
type Hit<T> = {
  _index: string;
  _type: string;
  _id: string;
  _score: number;
  _source: T;
};

type ElasticSearchResponse<T> = {
  hits: {
    hits: Hit<T>[];
  };
};

export const elasticSearchResponseBuilder = <T>(sources: T[], isIdSpecified = false): ElasticSearchResponse<T> => {
  const stubElasticSearchMeta = {
    _index: 'someIndex',
    _type: 'someType',
    _id: '123',
    _score: 1,
  };

  const hits = isIdSpecified
    ? sources.map((e: T & { _id: string }) => {
        const { _id, ...rest } = e;
        const a: T = rest; //type error
        const ret = { ...stubElasticSearchMeta, _id, _source: rest };
        return ret;
      })
    : sources.map((e) => ({ ...stubElasticSearchMeta, _source: e }));

  const response: ElasticSearchResponse<T> = {
    hits: {
      hits,
    },
  };

  return response;
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your constructed type is not always assignable to `T`, because it has no property named `_id`, but `T` might:

```js
type YourType<T> = Omit<T & { _id: string; }, "_id">

type Foo = {a: number, b: string, _id: string}

// {a: number, b: string}
type Bar = YourType<Foo>
```

In this case, `Bar` is not logically equal to `Foo`, and is not a subtype of `Foo` (it is, however, a supertype). In general, your type will be equivalent to `Omit<T, '_id'>`, which is a supertype of `T` but not necessarily equal to `T`.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAmg9gVwE4BVwQDwoHxQLxQDyAtgJbBZQBkUA3lAPqkAmAXFAM7BKkB2A5gG4oAXwA0UAERNmk7ACh5oSFABicOPjoBDdrwTEARhCQTD7LjwESZF7n34jFAemc69B46ajnO9gU7K0ABC2kha8MhokBjqcApAA)